# Linear Programming Problem, notation confusion

Tags: notation, linear-programming

While trying to implement an algorithm from [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10107-003-0492-5.pdf) I must solve a linear programming probelm. [linear programming problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iyMG.png).

I am confused about what the vertical lines indicate. I believe that this is not the vector norm since the equations are linear. I would be grateful if someone could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does look like vector norm.  This does not destroy linearity because the argument of the norm does not contain any decision variables.

Comment: could you please elaborate on what you mean by decision variables?

Comment: Here, $\rho$ and $x$ are the decision variables, which the solver is free to determine.  But everything else ($\tau_r$, $c$, $a(y)$, and $b(y)$) are fixed constants.